# ANTLR4 negative lookahead in lexer

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to define lexer rules for PostgreSQL SQL.

The problem is with the operator definition and the line comments conflicting with each other.

for example `@---` is an operator token `@-` followed by the `--` comment and not an operator token `@---`

In `grako` it would be possible to define the negative lookahead for the `-` fragment like:

```
OP_MINUS: '-' ! ( '-' ) .
```

In ANTLR4 I could not find any way to rollback already consumed fragment.

Any ideas?

Here the original definition what the PostgreSQL operator can be:

```
The operator name is a sequence of up to NAMEDATALEN-1
(63 by default) characters from the following list:

 + - * / < > = ~ ! @ # % ^ & | ` ?

There are a few restrictions on your choice of name:
-- and /* cannot appear anywhere in an operator name,
since they will be taken as the start of a comment.

A multicharacter operator name cannot end in + or -,
unless the name also contains at least one of these
characters:

~ ! @ # % ^ & | ` ?

For example, @- is an allowed operator name, but *- is not.
This restriction allows PostgreSQL to parse SQL-compliant
commands without requiring spaces between tokens.
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you're trying to do, what you already attempted, and why that didn't solve your problem?

Comment: So I need the lexer to return Op class, that (for simplification) can contain `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` in any combination. But `--` and `/*` start the comment, and the lexer should be able to return `+--this_is_plus`as two tokens: `Op(+)` and `LineComment(--this_is_plus)` and not as `Op(+--)` and `Ident(this_is_plus)`

Comment: Have you tried it? What you are describing that you want is the only way ANTLR works.

Comment: The operator token always consists of a `@` followed by exactly 1 character?

Comment: No, the operator token is 1 to 63 character long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a semantic predicate in your lexer rules to perform lookahead (or behind) without consuming characters. For example, the following covers several rules for an operator.

```
OPERATOR
  : ( [+*<>=~!@#%^&|`?]
    | '-' {_input.LA(1) != '-'}?
    | '/' {_input.LA(1) != '*'}?
    )+
  ;
```

However, the above rule does not address the restrictions on including a `+` or `-` at the end of an operator. To handle that in the easiest way possible, I would probably separate the two cases into separate rules.

```
// this rule does not allow + or - at the end of a rule
OPERATOR
  : ( [*<>=~!@#%^&|`?]
    | ( '+'
      | '-' {_input.LA(1) != '-'}?
      )+
      [*<>=~!@#%^&|`?]
    | '/' {_input.LA(1) != '*'}?
    )+
  ;

// this rule allows + or - at the end of a rule and sets the type to OPERATOR
// it requires a character from the special subset to appear
OPERATOR2
  : ( [*<>=+]
    | '-' {_input.LA(1) != '-'}?
    | '/' {_input.LA(1) != '*'}?
    )*
    [~!@#%^&|`?]
    OPERATOR?
    ( '+'
    | '-' {_input.LA(1) != '-'}?
    )+
    -> type(OPERATOR)
  ;
```

Comment: wow, I'm having a real hard time deciphering this x'] haha.. To put the first rule into words, An operator matches:
Either one of : `[*<>=~!@#%^&|'?]`, or  ((1 or many : `+` or (`-` without another `-` ahead)) followed by either of : `[*<>=~!@#%^&|'?]`), or a `/` without a `*` ahead of it.

Is this correct ? Or did i misunderstand some part of it