# ANTLR4 Negative lookahead workaround?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer, regex-lookarounds

I'm using antlr4 and I'm trying to make a parser for Matlab. One of the main issue there is the fact that comments and transpose both use single quotes. What I was thinking of a solution was to define the STRING lexer rule in somewhat the following manner:

`(if previous token is not ')','}',']' or [a-zA-Z0-9]) than match '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\''|'\r'|'\n') )* '\'`' (but note I do not want to consume the previous token if it is true).

Does anyone knows a workaround this problem, as it does not support negative lookaheads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do negative lookahead in ANTLR4 using `_input.LA(-1)` (in Java, see [how to resolve simple ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493732/how-to-resolve-simple-ambiguity/28503214#28503214) or [ANTLR4 negative lookahead in lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194110/antlr4-negative-lookahead-in-lexer)).

You can also use lexer mode to deal with this kind of stuff, but your lexer had to be defined in its own file. The idea is to go from a state that can match some tokens to another that can match new ones.

Here is an example from [ANTLR4 lexer documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-mode(),pushMode(),popMode,andmore):

```
// Default "mode": Everything OUTSIDE of a tag
COMMENT : '<!--' .*? '-->' ;
CDATA : '<![CDATA[' .*? ']]>' ;
OPEN : '<'                     -> pushMode(INSIDE) ;
 ...
XMLDeclOpen : '<?xml' S        -> pushMode(INSIDE) ;
...

// ----------------- Everything INSIDE of a tag ------------------    ---
mode INSIDE;
CLOSE : '>'         -> popMode ;
SPECIAL_CLOSE: '?>' -> popMode ; // close <?xml...?>
SLASH_CLOSE : '/>'  -> popMode ;
```

Comment: Do you know anyway to specify a range in the semantic predicate, e.g. {_input.LA(-1) != [a-zA-Z0-9]} ?

Comment: This code is directly put in the generated lexer (the code is directly put in java/your_target_language into the generated lexer), so I don't think you can't use directly range. However, as it is Java (or your target language) which is copied in your lexer, you can use `matches(...)` or equivalent functions. 
However, in your case, the use of lexer modes should be more appropriate.